# Extract .wav from .mp4 at a specific audio sample rate and frame rate

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a .mp4 file A recorded 59.94 fps that is then converted to 60 fps. I wish to extract the .wav from file A and put it to file B. This thread tells me how to extract the .wav file [Extracting wav from mp4 while preserving the highest possible quality](https://superuser.com/questions/609740/extracting-wav-from-mp4-while-preserving-the-highest-possible-quality)

```
ffmpeg -i file_A.mp4 audio_A.wav
```

But the resulting .wav file I get is one that has been sampled at 48kHz and at 59.94fps. How do I extract the .wav from file A at 60 fps and 48 kHz? E.g. the command should look something like this.

```
ffmpeg -i file_A.mp4 audio_A.wav --fps 60 --sample_rate 48000
```

Comment: A wav file doesn't have an fps. It is not a value appropriate to audio files.

Comment: how do i fit the audio from file A into file B then ? do i have to set the appropriate sample rate ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise the tempo a bit using the atempo filter.

Tempo adjustment is (60)/(60000/1001) = 1001/1000 = 1.001

```
ffmpeg -i file_A.mp4 -af atempo=1.001 audio_A.wav
```